# How to merge multiple rows sharing id into one single row (PYSPARK)

Tags: pyspark

I have this dataframe in PySpark . I want to get unique values for col3.
In SQL , I would group by on col1 and get max(col3) as col3

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   0|   1|   0|
|   0|   1|   0|
|   0|   1|   0|
|   1|   1|   0|
|   1|   1|   1|
|   1|   1|   1|
|   2|   1|   0|
|   2|   1|   1|
|   2|   1|   0|
+----+----+----+

This is the expected output:

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   0|   1|   0|
|   1|   1|   1|
|   2|   1|   1|
+----+----+----+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do same logic in pyspark .groupBy on col1,col2 and then agg get the max col3 value.

- other way would be using window **`row_number`** function and `partitionby` col1,col2 and `orderby desc` col3 and select only the **`rownumber == 1`**

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   0|   1|   0|
#|   0|   1|   0|
#|   0|   1|   0|
#|   1|   1|   0|
#|   1|   1|   1|
#|   1|   1|   1|
#|   2|   1|   0|
#|   2|   1|   1|
#|   2|   1|   0|
#+----+----+----+

df.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(max("col3").alias("col3")).orderBy("col3").show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   0|   1|   0|
#|   1|   1|   1|
#|   2|   1|   1|
#+----+----+----+
```

---

**`Using row_number():`**

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("col1","col2").orderBy(desc("col3"))

df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") == 1).drop("rn").orderBy("col3").show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   0|   1|   0|
#|   1|   1|   1|
#|   2|   1|   1|
#+----+----+----+
```